# TextView.setText() in fragment crashes app

Tags: android, crash, fragment, sensors

I am trying to change `TextView` content on Sensor change but after calling `TextView.setText("foo");` app crashes as if the `TextView` variable was null. I set up the  `TextView` variable in `onCreateView`. Here is the code:

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener
{
    private SensorManager mSrMgr = null;
    private Sensor mLight;
    private TextView page1;
    protected View mView;


    public fragment1()
    {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        mSrMgr = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mLight = mSrMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        page1 = container.findViewById(R.id.page1);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
        this.mView = view;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
    }

    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        this.unregister();
    }

    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        this.registerSensorListiner();
    }

    private void registerSensorListiner()
    {
        mSrMgr.registerListener(this, mLight, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    private void unregister()
    {
        mSrMgr.unregisterListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),String.valueOf(event.values[0]),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        page1.setText("elo"); //here is the crashing part
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Crash logs if you have any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{            
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
   this.mView = view;
   page1 = view.findViewById(R.id.page1);
   return view;
}
```

Instead of this

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        page1 = container.findViewById(R.id.page1);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
        this.mView = view;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First, inflate the layout

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
this.mView = view;
page1 = view.findViewById(R.id.page1); 
return view, false);
```

use `view` object to call findViewById method

Comment: Welcome, You can accept the answer and also uvote it :-) Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Why Multiple times **`R.layout.`** ?

```
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
        this.mView = view;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
```

It should be One Time. At first modify here.

**Note**

You will get [**`NullPointerException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an
>   object is required.

You should pass **`View's object`** .

```
page1 = view.findViewById(R.id.page1);
```

**Finally**

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
 page1 = view.findViewById(R.id.page1);
 this.mView = view;
 return view;
```

Comment: You are right, it was just some mess left from experimenting, thanks for notice.

Comment: @hdw3 Indeed. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager mSrMgr = null;
    private Sensor mLight;
    private TextView page1;
    protected View mView;


    public fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        mSrMgr = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mLight = mSrMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
        page1 = mView.findViewById(R.id.page1);
        return mView;
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.unregister();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.registerSensorListiner();
    }

    private void registerSensorListiner() {
        mSrMgr.registerListener(this, mLight, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    private void unregister() {
        mSrMgr.unregisterListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(event.values[0]), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        page1.setText("elo"); //here is the crashing part
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put your `findViewById` code in `onActivityCreated` like below:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        page1 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.page1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when creating layouts in fragments you copy and paste xml code that has duplicate IDs. When you then call the id of the pasted resources it will try to invoke the first defined resources which is probably null at runtime. Double check if the page1 id is found only in one fragment's Xml. If not work around "findviewbyid".I hope that helps, there's little detail in your code(Error msg)